# Binding multiple sources in listview

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am trying to learn XAML with WINRT and I have a question about binding and viewmodels.

I have an two classes EmployeeList and DownloadableEmployee:

```
public sealed class EmployeeList
{
public IReadOnlyList<DownloadableEmployee> DownloadableEmployees { get; }

}

public sealed class DownloadableEmployee
{
public System.Boolean IsSelected { get; set; }
public System.String Name { get; }

//method
public IAsyncOperation<IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType> GetEmployeePicAsync();
}
```

I have binded the EmployeeList to a **Multi Selectable ListView** displaying employee Names and Pictures. A user can now select / deselect individual employee in the ListView.

To achieve that, I've have created a DownloadableItem class that acts as a ViewModel which is binded to my listview EmployeeLV.

```
public class DownloadableItemVM
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType EnmployeePic
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

      public DownloadableItem(string name, IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType     thumbnail)
        {
            Name = name;
            Thumbnail = thumbnail;
        }
}

 ObservableCollection<DownloadableItemVM> employeesToDownload = new ObservableCollection<DownloadableItemVM>();

// set source to ListView
EmployeeLV.ItemsSource = employeesToDownload;

foreach (DownloadableEmployee item in EmployeeList.DownloadableEmployees)
                {
                    IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType stream = await item.GetEmployeePicAsync();                    
                    employeesToDownload.Add(new DownloadableItemVM(item.Name, stream));
                }
```

My List View

```
 <ListView x:Name="employeeLV" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Question XAML experts:

My ListView already binds to my custom View Model class DownloadableItemVM and properly displays the name and photo of each employee.

But now I have a problem because I need to "bind" each selected item in My ListView back to DownloadableEmployee.IsSelected such that when a user selects an employee, their "IsSelected" gets set to true and vice versa when they deselect.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to have all DownloadableEmployee object inside your DownloadableItemVM, and bind to name, picture, etc. through this object ? E.g.

```
public class DownloadableItemVM
{
    ...
    public DownloadableEmployee Employee
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    ...
    public DownloadableItem(DownloadableEmployee employee, IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType thumbnail)
    {
        Employee= employee;
        Thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }
    ...
}

 <ListView x:Name="employeeLV" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Employee.Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

With this approach you can reach your IsSelected prop through Employee object. Is this suitable for you ?

Comment: Thank you, that is a great idea! In my ListView, how would I go about binding my SelectedItem to {Binding  Employee.IsSelected} ?

Comment: Write style for your ListViewItem and bind inside setter: <Setter Property="IsSelected" value="{Binding Employee.IsSelected}"/>

Comment: struggling with the syntax here :(

Under 
<ListView x:Name="employeeLV" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
I have 
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Employee.IsSelected}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

Is this what you mean ?

Comment: Yep, but if you want to set IsSelected from your viewmodel, you should use TwoWay binding mode.

Comment: As a test , I set the IsSelected property to always be "True" and I don't see any of the listitems being as selected ...Am I not placing the ItemContainerStyle in the right place ?
 <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
what is a good way to debug the issue ? Thank you very much for helping Nazar!

Comment: Unfortunately, bindings are not supported on Setters in WinRT. I think Silverlight only got them in version 5. For workarounds you basically could define an attached dependency property that sets up the binding for you. You can have a look here: http://blog.onedevjob.com/2011/10/26/workaround-for-binding-not-supported-on-stylesettervalue-in-silverlight/